# Joining two arrays in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two arrays

```
list1=[{AcctId: 22, days: {Mon: 2.3, Tue: 6, Wed: 9}}, {AcctId: 39, days:{Mon: 3, Tue: 5, Wed:4.5}}]

list2=[{AcctId: 22, times: {t1: 4, t2: 4, t3: 9}}, {AcctId: 39, times: {t1: 3, t2: 6, t3: 1}}]
```

I want to join these two list3 in ng-repeat or in my controller so I get output like

```
list2=[{AcctId: 22, dtime:[ {Mon: {M:2.3, t1: 4}, tue:{T: 6, t2: 4}, Wed:{W:9, t3: 9}]}, {AcctId: 39, dtime: [{Mon: {M:3, t1:3}, tue:{T:5 , t2: 6}, Wed:{W:4.5, t3:1}]}
```

Please let me know what is the best way to join these two arrays into one
Thanks

Comment: How about letting us know what you tried and what isn't working.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide an example that uses valid arrays?

Comment: I tried Extend and filter called groupBy they both seem to do there work but it only works with One list. I have two and I have no idea what to do. Other then using nested for loops but that doesn't sounds attractive solution. So I am here seeing if I am missing something or some one has better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't really hard to search for [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). Also, combining [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) with [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) or [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), can do the same, albeit longer.